# chrome.tabs.update stops working when called from extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I tried the following code. It basically takes a screenshot from all tabs open in the current window:

```
function captureWindowTabs(windowId, callbackWithDataUrlArray) {
  var dataUrlArray = [];

  // get all tabs in the window
  chrome.windows.get(windowId, { populate: true }, function(windowObj) {
    var tabArray = windowObj.tabs;

    // find the tab selected at first
    for(var i = 0; i < tabArray.length; ++i) {
      if(tabArray[i].active) {
        var currentTab = tabArray[i];
        break;
      }
    }

    // recursive function that captures the tab and switches to the next
    var photoTab = function(i) {
      chrome.tabs.update(tabArray[i].id, { active: true }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(windowId, { format: "png" }, function(dataUrl) {
          // add data URL to array
          dataUrlArray.push({ tabId:tabArray[i].id, dataUrl: dataUrl });

          // switch to the next tab if there is one
          if(tabArray[i+1]) {
            photoTab(i+1);
          }
          else {
            // if no more tabs, return to the original tab and fire callback
            chrome.tabs.update(currentTab.id, { active: true }, function() {
              callbackWithDataUrlArray(dataUrlArray);
            });
          }
        });
      });
    };
    photoTab(0);
  });
}
```

When I call this code from popup.html opened as a webpage, it works as expected (I trigger this from a button click in the popup.html). When I call it from the browser extension, it just gets interrupted from the first tab it selects. Any idea why that is? I can't share errors, since the debugger gets closed when called from the extension.

Supplementary, is there a way to achieve desired result without needing the visual tab switching?

Answer (score 0):

While updating the next tab as `active tab`. make sure current tab is no more active tab by doing

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabArray[i-1].id, { active: false }, ()=>{});
```

Comment: It's not working. The moment the first tab gets activated from the popup, the debugger just stops, the rest of the code doesn't get executed.

Comment: I think it's because I have to move it to the background to keep it running. Thanks.

Comment: yup. `popup js` stops executing after popup is closed

Answer (score 0):

Moving the extension to a background script fixed the problem.

Reasoning is that the popup will close once the tab switches. Hence it is required to run in the background where it is not interrupted when the popup closes.